Pinescript error 'end of line without line continuation'
I am not a pinescript ninja. I am working on to finalize a strategy but it keeps giving me an error  'end of line without line continuation'. I have formatted code multiple time by 4 spaces or a tab but it won't work. I have tried here and chat gpt but I can't make it work. it keeps giving me error
How can I share my code here or if someone can message  me directly to fix the problem. It is driving me crazy. Here is the code and there are different versions I have tried as below in my own replies. If someone can help me, that would be great.
BP = iff(close < open, 
        iff(close[1] < open, math.max(high - close[1], close - low), 
            math.max(high - open, close - low)),
        iff(close > open,     
        iff(close[1] > open, high - low, 
            math.max(open - close[1], high - low)),
        iff(high - close > close - low, 
        iff(close[1] < open, math.max(high - close[1], close - low), high - open),
        iff(high - close < close - low, 
        iff(close[1] > open, high - low,
            math.max(open - close[1], high - low)),
        iff(close[1] > open, math.max(high - open, close - low),
        iff(close[1] < open, math.max(open - close[1], high - low),
            high - low)))))))


To avoid an if chain, try a switch
var BP = 0.0
switch
    close[1] < open  => BP := math.max(high - close[1], close - low)
    close[1] > open  => BP := math.max(high - open, close - low)

